# Makefile error in Protobuf 2.6.0 (Windows 10 Mingw)

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers

I tried to install Protobuf 2.6.0 on Windows, with Mingw.
The command `./configure` worked, it provided me a Makefile, but when I use the command `mingw32-make` to run the Makefile I have this error:

> C:\Users\taka\gz-ws\protobuf-2.6.0> mingw32-make
>
> ! était inattendu. //translation: "! was not expected"
>
> Makefile:558: recipe for target 'config.h' failed
>
> mingw32-make: *** [config.h] Error 255

The line 558 of the Makefile:

```
config.h: stamp-h1
    @if test ! -f $@; then rm -f stamp-h1; else :; fi
    @if test ! -f $@; then $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) stamp-h1; else :; fi`
```

I don't know what to do here.

Comment: Did you try making using Msys? mingw32-make does not have access to all unix bash which can cause a lot of problems. Also, I was able to successfully install protobuf on msys using the package manager - you should be able to get a precompiled version there.

Comment: It woked, thank you!

Comment: It might be a good idea to post your findings as a detailed answer. This way other SO users will have an easier time setting up their Protobuf on MinGW.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be very useful for other people having the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to use Msys and not MinGW, be cause MinGW doesn't have access to all Unix Bash. (run make and not mingw32-make)

So it cannot recognize the line 558 but Msys can read it correctly.